# how to call the function of the same class inside another function of that class in php

Tags: php

when i am calling the function connect and closeDb inside showAll there is an error.

```
class DBConnect {

private $con;

private function connect() {

    $con = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
    mysql_select_db('school');
}

private function closeDb() {
    mysql_close($this->con);
}

public function showAll() {
    self::connect();

    echo "THis is from the showAll method";
    self::closeDb();
}
```

}

[image]

Comment: If it is static use self. Use `$this->function()` instead. And you didnt assign the `$this->con` to anything

Comment: no this is not the static

Comment: how do i call inside showAll funciton to connect and closeDb

Comment: $this->connect(); $this->closeDb();

Comment: There are already very good database classes that have all these methods in place. Look into PDO, its my preferred class.

Comment: thanks i got my point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Mysql extension was deprecated in PHP 5.5.0, and it was removed in PHP 7.0.0. Instead, the MySQLi or PDO_MySQL extension should be used.
>
> Learn basics of object oriented programming: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php

Answer (score 0):

This Line looks false.
`$con = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");`

If think you want to do 
`$this->con = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");`

Then

`public function showAll() {
        $this->connect();
        echo "THis is from the showAll method";
        $this->closeDb();
}`

**use $this !**